# First character in input unselectable/uneditable

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have an input where the user can enter an HEX value. The "#" sign is part of the background image of the input field so the user only needs to enter numbers. I'd like to have the "#" sign as html and make it unselectable/uneditable. Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps this might help - [Is there a way to make a text area partially editable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444874/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-text-area-partially-editable-make-only-portions-of-th)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listen for a `keyup` event in the input element, then within the handler you can force the value of the input to always starts with `#` char and followed by 0-9/a-f

```
$('#input').bind('keyup', function(){
    var sanitized = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9a-f]/g,'');
    $(this).val('#'+sanitized);
});
```

See the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/QrrjW/1/

Comment: Nice solution. However, it'll be cooler if you bind to the keydown event :)

Comment: @Jørgen Initially I thought of that too :) but since `keydown` takes the input value before the triggered key inserted, last chars won't get sanitized http://jsfiddle.net/QrrjW/2/

Answer (score 0):

put x char in input box as default value.using js manage .if user first charector type # then ok else type # using js and user's typed charactor in js.