# How to set readOnly property to selected text inside a html textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to make a text area partially editable? (make only portions of the text editable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444874/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-text-area-partially-editable-make-only-portions-of-th)

Any suggestions on how to set readOnly property to selected text inside a html textarea.
Here is an image of selected text inside textarea..

[image]

Any guidance and help is appreciated..!

Comment: Is it possible to set readOnly property to a selected text?

Comment: What have you tried? `Here is an image of selected text inside textarea` where?

Comment: Please check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/WSrww/

Comment: You mean to set `readonly` only to the selected part of the text? No.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reptn to upload an image

Comment: I am sure you must have searched for similar resources. But I would request you to crosscheck this out [(Is there a way to make a text area partially editable? (make only portions of the text editable)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5444998/1268844)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand about what you wanted, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WSrww/3/) is a working solution.

Here is the code:

```
$("#my-text").select(function() {
    $(this).readonly = true;
});
$("#my-text").mouseup(function() {
    $(this).readonly = false;
});
$("#my-text").keydown(function() {
    $(this).readonly = false;
});
```

Basically I am making use of `select` event to make the textarea `readonly`. And, removing the `read only` attribute on `click` and `keydown` using `removeAttr`.

Thanks to @Bergi for pointing to `readonly` attribute of jQuery objects.

Comment: argh, just set the property `this.readonly = true/false;` instead of juggling around with attributes.

Comment: It doesn't work for me , by default my code will select the text "only" and i want to make that text uneditable or readonly