# Javascript make a word not editable into the text area

Tags: javascript

I have a basic text area.
I need a javascript function that will write a word ( i.e. #default ) into this textarea and will make ONLY this word not editable.
The rest of the textarea should remain writable as normal. Only the words defined via javascript should not be editable by the user.
Is there a way to do it that will work on IE7as well?

Thanks for the support.

Comment: So, you want us to do your homework?

Comment: @Shikiryu if I am posting it here it's maybe because I have searched for a solution with no results. Isn't it the reason of stackoverflow? Sharing the knowledge? Your comment has really no sense. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @DavidStarkey I tried this with no luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444874/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-text-area-partially-editable-make-only-portions-of-th

Comment: @user1929719 well, then, your question is not well asked.

Comment: Indeed stackoverflow is meant to be used after people research themselves but this is occasionally abused.  Please excuse the assumptions made.

How much editing vs. permanent are we talking here?  Is this like a madlib where they just need a word here or there?

Comment: It's only one word at the begin of the text area that will always begin with a #, such as #thisisatag. Only the first word should be not editable. The rest of the textarea should remain writable

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `text-indent` to the textarea and then giving absolute position to the hashtag. I'm not sure it's going to work in IE7, but here's an example that works in Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/c5ZKk/

HTML:

```
<div class="hashtag">#hashtag</div>
<textarea>editable text</textarea>
```

CSS:

```
body, textarea {
    font: 14px/1.5 Arial, sans-serif;
}

.hashtag {
    position: absolute;
    color: #aaa;
    margin: 6px 0 0 5px;
}

textarea {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    text-indent: 62px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```