# Having non removable text in Textarea but still being able to add to it?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, textarea

I want to have a textarea that starts with "I am " but it is non removable, like I want it to always be there not a placeholder as well as no one can remove it which gets hidden when text is starting to be written. How would I do this for a textarea.

**Code From Fiddle**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="prefix" value="prefix_" >
```

**Javascript**

```
$('input.prefix').keyup(function(){
   var prefix = 'prefix_';
    if(!(this.value.match('^prefix_'))){
         this.value = prefix;                
    }        
});

$('input.prefix').blur(function(){
   var prefix = 'prefix_';
    if(!(this.value.match('^prefix_'))){
         this.value = prefix;                
    }        
});
```

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [help])

Comment: I tried a javascript option but the problem is if you remove the required text it removes everything the user has written ( http://jsfiddle.net/vBBpS/2/ )

Comment: Background image and text-indent. Not sexy but it would work

Comment: I think you should take a look at this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444874/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-text-area-partially-editable-make-only-portions-of-th)

Answer (score 0):

The code in your fiddel is close. Instead of replacing the content with `prefix` replace it with `prefix` and the value

```
$('input.prefix').keyup(function(){
   var prefix = 'prefix_';
    if(!(this.value.match('^prefix_'))){
         this.value = prefix + this.value;                
    }        
});

$('input.prefix').blur(function(){
   var prefix = 'prefix_';
    if(!(this.value.match('^prefix_'))){
         this.value = prefix + this.value;                
    }        
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vBBpS/1/

On a side note, you should move the common code to a function.