# Don't select first word in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to have a textarea begin with the string "Notes:". But when the user clicks inside the textarea, the cursor cannot go into that string, or when all the text in the textarea is selected, "Notes:" is not included. Is this even possible? Is there a better solution that's not just a label above or a `placeholder`?

Comment: I don't understand why placeholder won't do the job here.....

Comment: That's exactly what a placeholder is for.

Comment: Have you tried this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444874/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-text-area-partially-editable-make-only-portions-of-th

Comment: @patricksweeney I would like the "placeholder" to remain even after the user has clicked inside. Can that functionality be added to placeholder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* hack around the selection range, disable events etc. But I would just use `text-indent` on the textarea and position the `Note:` label absolute inside using CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/nm5tr/

Something like:

```
<div>
    <label for="ta">Note:</label>
    <textarea id="ta" cols=20 rows=4>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</textarea>
</div>

<style>
div{position:relative}
label{position:absolute;top:5px;left:5px;font:16px/1 sans-serif}
textarea{text-indent:2.5em;font:16px/1 sans-serif;padding:5px;margin:0}
</style>
```

For what it’s worth, this also makes semantic sense (sort of).

Comment: That's very cool. I was trying something like that, but wasn't aware of text-indend. Thanks.