# Not editable,removable part of a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple textarea and It has a default value. I want to hold this value everytime. User should not remove this value but he can add extra string.

```
<textarea>This is contstant</textarea>
```

As you see above. It has a default value. How can I protect this value? But user can add something after default value like below.

```
<textarea>This is contstant and extra things by user</textarea>
```

So how can do a partially editable textarea with default value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make a text area partially editable? (make only portions of the text editable)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444874/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-text-area-partially-editable-make-only-portions-of-th)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach an event handler to the `<textarea>` that does a simple validation every time it changes.  If it tries to change to where your constant is partially destroyed, overwrite the X characters of the string value.

```
$('#foo').keydown(function () {
    if ($(this).val().indexOf("This is constant.  ") !== 0) {
        var length = "This is constant.  ".length;
        var current = $(this).val();
        var after = current.slice(length);

        $(this).val("This is constant.  " + after);
    }
});
```

Here is a example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swwuuhjd/).

I recommend using JQuery for this because `<textarea>` doesn't actually have a `value`, or I think even a `text` attribute that you can check.  JQuery just abstracts away `<textarea>`'s quirks.

Comment: @Eclecticist strange behavior if the user clicks to the beginning of the textarea or into the middle of the default value and starts typing

Comment: @mapleafman True enough.  In my experience, all of the key-related events have strange behavior.  The best solution is probably to avoid needing to have a required substring at the beginning of a textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way:

1. Style the `textarea` to remove the border.
2. Put a `div` on top which contains the constant text.
3. Wrap both elements in a `div` to give it a common border.

That way, the constant text will appear as if it was part of the `textarea` but it's not.

When you submit the form, prepend the static text to the field value.

Comment: This is a nice idea. Google translate page using this approach as I see