# Keep initial value in textbox after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to keep an initial value/placeholder in my textbox after it's clicked. It needs to be readonly but allow the user to add characters in after the preset text:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="I will " name="title" required maxlength="50">
```

When the user clicks in the textbox, I need it to move their cursor to after the word "I will" and allow them to type. They cannot be able to delete the words "I will".

Comment: You are making this more complicated than what it should be, just do this: `<label>I will <input type="text" name="title" required maxlenght="50" /></label>` and style it with css so that it looks like it's the same textbox.

Comment: There's some more ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444874/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-text-area-partially-editable-make-only-portions-of-th).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this basic example based on **@Josep** suggestion :

```css
label{
    border: 1px solid;
}
input{
    border: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<label>I will <input type="text" name="title" required maxlenght="50" /></label>
```

`Outline: none` will remove the blue box around the input in major browsers. (Just one aesthetic improvement)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `focusout` event to reset `value` , `readonly` attributes after `click` event

```js
$("input").on({
  click:function(e) {
    $(this).removeAttr("readOnly")
  }, 
  focusout: function(e) {    
    this.value = this.getAttribute("placeholder") 
                 + this.value.replace(/^I will /, "");
    $(this).prop("readOnly", true);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" placeholder="I will " name="title" required maxlength="50" readonly>
```